# Page is refreshing on JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to build a page that would allow a user to input text into a text field and hit enter on their keyboard and it would return the top 10 Wikipedia entries with that text.

Currently, my concern is that the page refreshes every time it fetches the JSON. I attempted the e.preventDefault() method, as I read about on other questions, but it isn't working. Can someone help me understand why this auto-refresh is happening, and how to fix it? Thank you.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form action="#">
    <input id="search" name="query" onkeyup="" type="text"></input>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

And here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").on("keyup", function(e) {

    // attempt to prevent page refresh
    e.preventDefault();

    // if key pressed is "enter"
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

      // retrieve user input
      var search = document.getElementById("search").value;

      // build Wikipedia API url
      var request = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=" + search + "&format=json&callback=?";

      $.getJSON(request, function(json) {
      var x = json.query.search[0]["snippet"];
      $(".main").html(x);
      });
    };
  });
});
```

Here's a link: https://codepen.io/lieberscott/pen/RLVaGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you submit the form (pressing enter does that). The form submits to the current page which looks like a reload.

```
<form id="searchform>
    <input id="search" name="query" onkeyup="" type="text"></input>
  </form>

$('#searchform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // your magic here.
});
```

The preventDefault stops the key UP, but by that time, you've already started submitting. The poreventDefault stops the enter getting input as text (you can check this with a textarea). If you'd change it to a letter, say A, you'd type the A, but not see it.

You can also remove the form itself, keeping just the input, if that doesnt create other issues, resulting in less HTML, which is nice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the page isn't triggering a JSON request upon the user pressing "Enter" on the keyboard now ...

Comment: No, you bind the enter->getJson. But the *native* functionallity of a browser means that you submit a form

Comment: Yes, removing the <form> tags did it. Thank you!

Comment: This is because you now no longer submit the form :)

Comment: Also, please mark a answer as solution if it solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<form>` tag from your HTML.

Comment: You can remove what? And why?

Comment: "And why?" This isnt a answer, the OP doesnt learn anything by thing.

Comment: @ishanshah this worked. I don't know why, but it did.

Comment: @Scott It worked because form tag submits the data to the server and hence the page gets refreshed. If you are not using submit then there is no use of form tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `form` and on `enter/return` it will try to submit the form.

Unless there is a `button type="submit"` or `input type='submit'` remove the form and use only input

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <input id="search" name="query" onkeyup="" type="text"></input>
</div>
<div class="main"></div>
</div>
```